Why can't find imported editable python package?

The dir1 directory structure:

dir1/
|-- helloworld/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- hello.py
|-- setup.py
|-- venv/ #The dir1 virtual environment


The dir2 directory structure:

dir2/
|-- app2.py
|-- venv/ #The dir2 virtual environment

# hello.py
def say_hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='helloworld',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)


Activate dir2 venv

C:\Users\TC\temp\editable\dir2>venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) C:\Users\TC\temp\editable\dir2>


Install helloworld package to the dir2 venv in editable mode.

(venv) C:\Users\TC\temp\editable\dir2>pip install -e C:\Users\TC\temp\editable\dir1


Import helloworld package from app2.py

# app2.py
from helloworld.hello import say_hello

print(say_hello())


Run app2.py

python app2.py

Now here is the problem. helloworld package is not found from app2.py. However, pip list does show that the helloworld package has been installed. Using VS Code, there is a yellow squiggly line underneath helloword.hello, which indicates that package not found.
This is a very simple setup to test the editable installation of a python package. I wonder the error is producible. Or this is a bug! OS is windows.
Please let me know if you get the same error or you will be able to get it to work.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Note:
You need to pip install setuptools in dir1 venv.

I'm on Windows and I followed your steps and it works for me, EXCEPT I never activated dir1 venv or installed setuptools.  I activated dir2 and ran pip install -e <path_to_dir2>, then ran python app2.py.  Not using VS Code...just cmd window on Windows.

Yes! This does work. All I did was deactivate dir1 venv, and follow your steps. However, in VS Code, it still can't find the helloworld package. This is my main concern.

Did you run the code anyway and see a problem?  Or just see the "yellow squiggly" and stop?

The code run but the yellow squiggly line is still underneath the helloworld.hello, I wonder if you has the problem.

If I don't use editable mode, it works fine, and helloworld.hello turns green. VS Code is able to locate the package. However, it doesn't work under the editable mode. I wonder if this is a bug of VS Code or some sort.

Ensure that your VSCode instance is using the correct virtualenv, see thread and thread.

VS Code was indeed the correct virtualenv.

According to the accepted answer, the code works fine, so there is not a reproducible problem here. The fact that VS Code Intellisense apparently doesn't see/understand the installed editable wheel, is a bug / missing feature in VS Code, and should be reported to them instead.

# app2.py
from helloworld.hello import say_hello

print(say_hello())

After pip editable mode installation,
(venv) C:\Users\TC\temp\editable\dir2>pip install -e C:\Users\TC\temp\editable\dir1

the following error appears in app2.py.
Import "helloworld.hello" could not be resolvedPylance(reportMissingImports)

However, the app2.py runs fine. If pip install without editable mode, the error message disappears and IntelliSense works.
I have tried many ways to get the IntelliSense to work under the editable mode without success.
Therefore I conclude for some unknown reason, helloworld package is not installed under the editable mode. Instead the following folders are installed in venv\lib\site-packages
2024-10-17  11:24 PM                91 __editable__.helloworld-0.1.0.pth
2024-10-17  11:24 PM             3,436 __editable___helloworld_0_1_0_finder.py

Since no helloworld package folder exists, Pylance therefore cannot resolve the import.
Problem solved.

Create a .env file in dir2.

PYTHONPATH=C:/Users/TC/temp/editable/dir1


Open settings.json in .vscode directory and make the following change.

{
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
}


"Therefore I conclude for some unknown reason, helloworld package is not installed under the editable mode." That's how editable-mode installs work. Pip created a wheel that just has that .pth and .py file, and unpacked it into site-packages. Python will use them to configure sys.path so that your installed project is available in the venv. VS Code doesn't understand this, because it can't just look at folder names - it would have to run the code in order to see how sys.path is changed.

For details, please see the PEP for modern editable wheels: https://peps.python.org/pep-0660/ . These were designed in order to support pyproject.toml based builds, but new versions of Pip will apparently still take this approach if you only use setup.py.

I believe the issue stems from the find_packages() in your setup.py which including the venv directory, causing import conflicts.
To fix this, modify your setup.py and exclude the venv.

How to modify setup.py so that it will work?
